# MariaDB: Select from a table colum based on another table field value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

id like to make a select in a specific field in table A based on the field name on a table B:

Table A:

```
id , name , value, field
1  , Test, 30, age
```

Table B:

```
id, name, date, username, email, password, birthdate, age, gender, optin
1, Robson, 2020-05-12, rob, rob@email.com, passwd, 1982-12-31, 37, M, 1
```

i need to make a select in table b like it:

```
SELECT TABLEB.(TABLEA.FIELD) from TABLEB where TABLEA.value>=TABLEB.(TABLEA.FIELD)
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
SELECT
  CASE TABLEA.FIELD
    WHEN 'age' THEN TABLEB.AGE
    WHEN 'gender' THEN TABLEB.GENDER
    -- etc
    ELSE NULL
  END CASE
  AS X
FROM TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.VALUE > X
```